# P&T Switch appearing 4 times in SafeCracker form

Tags: safecracker

I have a rather bizarre issue in my SafeCracker form: each P&T Switch field appears 4 times. They move independently. In the cpanel they appear fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Please paste your code...